# PHP Select Data from Json

Tags: php, arrays, json

My JSON Data

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "userid": 1,
      "username": "Admin",
      "usermail": "admin@admin.com",
      "authority": [
        {
          "authorityid": 1,
          "authoritytext": "Admin",
          "mission": [
            {
              "permission": "add"
            },
            {
              "permission": "delete"
            },
            {
              "permission": "move"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "authorityid": 1,
          "authoritytext": "Super Admin",
          "mission": [
            {
              "permission": "no add"
            },
            {
              "permission": "no delete"
            },
            {
              "permission": "only moderate"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

MY PHP

```
foreach($result->users as $ok)  {

     foreach($ok->authority as $okey) {

         foreach($okey->mission as $okeyokey) {

            $test = $okeyokey->permission;
            echo $test;

         }
     }
 }
```

How to make this?
I want show parse json only authority{0} -> misson{0} show "permission" "add" please help me .
Maybe look ScreenShot >>>>>
I want filter {0}{1}{2} and select 0 -> show parse json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xsmE.png)

Comment: Hello! Please don't add unrelated tags to your question. I don't see any relation to MySQL or curl in your question. In fact it doesn't even have to do with JSON parsing because you are asking about transformations of your object (that you may previously have got from parsing JSON but that is not part of your problem).

Comment: Should we assume you know about `json_decode()` or not?

Comment: Thank you. permission === 'add' >>> not ==='add'  >> not static update json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php

$jsonData = '{
  "users": [
    {
      "userid": 1,
      "username": "Admin",
      "usermail": "admin@admin.com",
      "authority": [
        {
          "authorityid": 1,
          "authoritytext": "Admin",
          "mission": [
            {
              "permission": "add"
            },
            {
              "permission": "delete"
            },
            {
              "permission": "move"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "authorityid": 1,
          "authoritytext": "Super Admin",
          "mission": [
            {
              "permission": "no add"
            },
            {
              "permission": "no delete"
            },
            {
              "permission": "only moderate"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}';

$data = json_decode($jsonData);
echo($data->users[0]->authority[0]->mission[0]->permission);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting objects and arrays confused

```
foreach($result->users as $currentUser){
    $auths = $currentUser->authority;
    foreach($auths as $currentAuth){
        foreach($currentAuth->mission as $permission){
          foreach($permission as $positionLabel => $permissionValue){
              if($permissionValue == "add"){
                  // code here
              }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you are using good labels. Dummy placeholders can be fine, but it makes tracking bugs really hard. I assume you want to check if they hold permission using a database, using PDO?

```
// array
$arr = ["this", "is", "an", "array"];
echo $arr[0] // prints out the word this. 
$json = { "attribute": "value"}
echo $json->attribute // prints out the word value.
```

You can have arrays in JSON objects, and JSON Objects in arrays. How you access them are different.

Comment: This will not work. You can try if you like to. Just FYI. So many `foreach` loops. You can simply do this in two loops or even without loops if OP want direct text `add` only.

Comment: It works, I wasn't sure if they ONLY wanted that one or now when I made that post.